# multi line field contents with append checked not being retrieved in email workflow

Tags: workflow, email

I have been reviewing the item below and still can't get this to work.  I have mirrored the column in the List settings and tried to retrieve it that way but I can't.  I am not able to get the most recent or historical entries.

I have tried using JS and jQuery to no avail.  Has someone had this issue lately?  All I'd like to do is send the entry that the user just made in the multi-line appeneded field prior to saving the form, in an email once the form is saved.

[sharepoint desinger workflow email - multiple line of text field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162650/sharepoint-desinger-workflow-email-multiple-line-of-text-field)

Comment: I found this article but it didn't solve the issue: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3095702/workflow-that-uses-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow-platform-type-contains-blank-values-in-output-from-the-multiple-lines-of-text-column

Comment: To get this to work, store the value of the entered multiple line field in a workflow variable at the BEGINNING of the workflow and BEFORE any other variables/fields were set.